# How to extend QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I'm trying to extend `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` to modify a query method:

```
public class SliceableRepositoryImpl<T>
        extends QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor<T>
        implements SliceableRepository<T> {
    public SliceableRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation,
                                   EntityManager entityManager,
                                   EntityPathResolver resolver,
                                   CrudMethodMetadata metadata) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager, resolver, metadata);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        //TODO modify
        return super.findAll(predicate, pageable);
    }
}

public interface MysRepository extends
        SliceableRepository<MyEntity>,
        JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}

public interface SliceableRepository<T> {
    Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Result:
`Parameter 0 of constructor in SliceableRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' that could not be found.`

Question: how can I actually extend `QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor` and let spring autowire the constructor parameters?